# How can I change bootstrap menu width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I change bootstrap menu width without affecting responsiveness? Below is my html:

```
<div class="page-header col-xs-12">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container col-xs-12">
        <div class="row navigation-row">
            <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background:none;border:0px;">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Following is my css:

```
@charset "utf-8";

    .page-header {
        background-color:#DDEFE6 !important;
        height:150px;
        margin:0px auto;
    }
    .navigation-row{
        background-color:#009547;
        padding:0px;
        height:50px;
    }
```

How can I change width of 'Home' menu?

Comment: Please add this into a snippet and what is it you exactly want to do. Increase the width of the 'home' link?

Comment: Yes, I want to increase width of my menus (Home, Page 1, Page 2 etc.)

Comment: What you exactly want to do? You mean to say you want to change width for small devices? or in all devices?

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing the padding between your navbar elements so they display futher apart and thus, appear to have a large width using the following CSS:

```
.navbar-nav > li {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Adjust as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

As James mentioned if you provide the `padding-left` and `padding-right`, it should work fine but its even better if you give those padding to the `<a>` elements inside the `<li>` rather than only the `<li>`. like so.

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

**Reason :** This would affect the menu links even with any dynamic classes attached like `active`.